# Is there an elegant way to check if a group of environment variables are set?

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables

Is there a way to elegantly check if a known number of environment variables are set?

This is on MacOS, running Python 3.7.3.  I'm creating a command-line app that will be connecting to a Google Sheet as well as a MySQL database.  Prior to making all of the connections, I would like an elegant way to check that ALL of the env. variables are set.  If one or more is NOT set, then I don't to try to connect to either Google or MySQL.

```py
try: 
    #print("Checking ENVIRONMENT variables...") 
    SPREADSHEET_ID = os.environ['SPREADSHEET_ID']
    SERVICE_ACCESS_FILE = os.environ['SERVICE_ACCESS_FILE']
    MYSQL_HOST = os.environ['MYSQL_HOST']
    MYSQL_DATABASE = os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE']
    MYSQL_ID = os.environ['MYSQL_UID']
    MYSQL_PWD = os.environ['MYSQL_PWD']
    MTEST = os.environ['MTEST']
    #print("All environment variables are set.")
except KeyError:  
    print("One or more Environment variables do not exist")
```

The aforementioned code works fine, but it would be nice if I could
have some clean way of checking each one.  I could do an "if exists" kind of thing for each variable, but that seems sloppy.  Is it better to put this in a function that will handle this?  And perhaps let the user know which variables are not set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily the best way, but here's a simple one liner:

```
env_vars = ['SPREADSHEET_ID', 'SERVICE_ACCESS_FILE', ...]
if not set(os.environ).issuperset(env_vars):
    print("One or more Environment variables do not exist")
```

Or even better:

```
missing = set(env_vars) - set(os.environ)
if missing:
    print("Environment variables do not exist: %s" % missing)
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a uber-cool pythonic way of doing this!  Many thanks!